# Windows 2003 Server and Core2Duo processor features

Tags: windows-server-2003, multi-core

I use my computer for development (ASP.NET 4.0/MS SQL Server 2008). I want to install Windows 2003 Server. But I want to know does Windows 2003 Server recognizes and utilizes full features of Core2Duo processor?

Answer (score 2):

No operating system does. Like almost all modern CPUs, the Core 2 Duo has conflicting features and it is effectively impossible to use them all from the same OS.

For example, 32-bit Windows can use both the 32-bit and 16-bit instruction sets, but not the 64-bit instruction set. 64-bit Windows can use both the 64-bit and 32-bit instruction sets, but not the 16-bit instruction set.

This is really precisely the wrong question to ask. For example, only a 64-bit edition of Windows would let you use the CPU's most advanced instruction set. But if you only have 1GB of memory, it will likely perform worse.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [x64 edition of server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003x64) to take full advantage of the processor.